# Anchoring popup position to the left of the screen in OpenLayers 6?

Tags: openlayers, javascript, popup

I have a popup when click to layer on map and popup displayed at selected position. I want to show popup to left screen. How can I do that?

This is my example to show feature in popup

```
var container = document.getElementById('popup');
    var content = document.getElementById('info');
    var closer = document.getElementById('popup-closer');
    var popup = new ol.Overlay({
        element: container,
        autoPan: true,
        autoPanAnimation: {
            duration: 250
        }
    });
    map.addOverlay(popup);
    closer.onclick = function(){
        popup.setPosition(undefined);
        closer.blur();
        return false;
    }
    // get data
    map.on('click', function (evt) {
        popup.setPosition(undefined);
        content.innerHTML = '';
        var viewResolution = mapView.getResolution();
        var url = source.getFeatureInfoUrl(
          evt.coordinate,
          viewResolution,
          'EPSG:3857',
          {
            'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json',
            'propertyName': 'soqd,doan,shthua,shbando,dientich' 
          },
        );
        if (url) {
            $.getJSON(url, function(data){
                var feature = data.features[0];
                var props = feature.properties;
                content.innerHTML = "<h2>Thông tin quy hoạch</h1><br>"
                                    + "<h3>Số thửa : </h3><p>" + props.shthua
                                    + "</p> <br> <h3>Số hiệu bản đồ : </h3><p>" + props.shbando
                                    + "</p> <br> <h3>Diện tích : </h3><p>"+ props.dientich + " m2"
                                    + "</p> <br> <h3>Đồ án : </h3><p>"+ props.doan 
                                    + "</p>" 
                popup.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
                // console.log(props);
            })
        }else{
            popup.setPosition(undefined);
        }
        console.log(url);
    });      
    map.on('pointermove', function (evt) {
        if (evt.dragging) {
          return;
        }
        var data = openGoVapLayer.getData(evt.pixel);
        var hit = data && data[3] > 0; // transparent pixels have zero for data[3]
        map.getTargetElement().style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';
    });
```

And my popup show like this (Images are for illustrative purposes only), but a want to anchor popup to left of screen
[image: And popup show like this]

I want to anchor popup like this but left side of the screen
[image]

Comment: @TomazicM thanks for reminding, I have updated my question

Comment: Please add also an image of how you would like popup to be placed. It also seems that arrow at the bottom of the popup would then have no sense, since it would point to the wrong location. And what should happen if user moves/panes the map up/down or left/right?

Comment: @TomazicM Sorry for the delay, i have updated my question, hope to get your help. thanks you a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use OpenLayers [ol-ext](https://github.com/Viglino/ol-ext) plugin [ol.control.Overlay](http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/doc/doc-pages/ol.control.Overlay.html) to display popup on the left side of the screen.

Code to display such popup could look something like this:

CSS

```
.ol-overlay.menu {
  width: 30%;
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000;
  padding: 0.5em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;
  transition: all 0.25s;
}
```

JS

```
var overlayControl = new ol.control.Overlay({
  className: "slide-left menu",
  hideOnClick: true
});
map.addControl(overlayControl);

map.on('singleclick', function (evt) {
  const coordinate = evt.coordinate;
  const hdms = ol.coordinate.toStringHDMS(ol.proj.toLonLat(coordinate));  
  overlayControl.show('<p>You clicked this point:</p><code>' + hdms + '</code>');
});
```

And this is the result upon clicking on the map:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I'm so sorry, I have a lot problem for my webgis, I'm try your suggestion and I have new problem with `ol.control.Overlay`  not a constructor. I'm newbie, sorry about that

Comment: You have to include references to `ol-ext` plugin into your code: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Viglino/ol-ext/master/dist/ol-ext.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Viglino/ol-ext/master/dist/ol-ext.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I sure i have include `ol-ext` plugin in my code with folder download from [https://openlayers.org/download/] with version v6.15.1-dist.zip. This is my code in html for include `<link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/v6.14.1-dist/ol.css">` and `<script src="libs/v6.14.1-dist/ol.js"></script>` . Did i miss something? Thank you a lot for reply

Comment: No, this is OpenLayers, I'm talking about OpenLayers **ol-ext plugin**, available at https://github.com/Viglino/ol-ext.

Comment: I did as you instructed and the error is still showing like below, please help me

Comment: You have to include both OpenLayers and ol-ext, and ol-ext should be included **after** OpenLayers include.

Comment: It work!!! Thank you a lot!! You save my day! ♥

Comment: I marked this answer is as accepted. Again, thank you a lot!